# openapi-generator: command not found for bash script

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have a `generate.sh` file with below lines of code,

```
#!/bin/bash

openapi-generator generate -g aspnetcore \
--template-dir ${PWD}/openapi-generator-aspnetcore3-templates/ \
--additional-properties aspnetCoreVersion=3.1 \
--additional-properties classModifier=abstract \
--additional-properties operationModifier=abstract \
--additional-properties packageName=RedHat.TodoList \
--additional-properties packageTitle=TodoList \
-i todo_openapi.yaml \
-o ${PWD}
```

When I am trying to run it `Git Bash` tool it's throwing error `./generate.sh: line 3: openapi-generator: command not found`, I can see  `openapi-generator-cli` commands working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In generate.sh, replace `openapi-generator` with `openapi-generator-cli` instead.

(`openapi-generator` is usually installed via brew on Mac)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like PATH problem.

Use `which openapi-generator` in terminal or Git Bash, whichever works for you, to find openapi-generator path first.

```
$ which openapi-generator
/usr/local/bin/openapi-generator
```

Then add the path to PATH variable in your `generate.sh`, e.g. put the following line before you call openapi-generator.

```
PATH+=:/usr/local/bin
```